# Docker in Docker(DND) is not starting

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I have a [simple Ubuntu 16.10 container](https://github.com/orsenthil/docker-library/blob/master/base.docker) which has `docker.io` installed.

The docker process terminates after it starts and log has this information. Any troubleshooting suggestions?

```
$ docker run -it --name dcos-ubuntu-python5 python-docker /bin/bash

root@5ff6bb6b6dc7:/# docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.

root@5ff6bb6b6dc7:/# service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                          [ OK ]
root@5ff6bb6b6dc7:/# service docker status
 * Docker is not running

root@5ff6bb6b6dc7:/# tail -f /var/log/docker.log
time="2017-12-21T17:09:45.464736873Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 50"
time="2017-12-21T17:09:46.472578239Z" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: operation not permitted"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to run docker within docker container?

Docker-in-Docker is developed to help docker development. And it needs `--privileged` flag to run docker container.(Please read jpetazzo's blog [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).)

If you really want to execute docker in docker container, you also have other options.

1. Bind mount docker.sock. Some people call this `DooD(Docker-outside-of-Docker)`

   docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
2. Install docker(client) and specify `DOCKER_HOST` to access remote docker daemon. Be careful about [socket protection with certificates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

Comment: I think, it is discouraging that you answer a question starting "Why do you want to run docker within docker container?"

Comment: This is because the way to execute docker in docker container depends on the purpose.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running docker as sudo  if not run as sudo or

Else add user group to docker

docker group. For this run following command:

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.

```
docker run -it --privileged --name dcos-ubuntu-python5 python-docker /bin/bash
```

(This was also mentioned partly in @SunghoMoon's response. So Credits to him).